# How to find Value X when Value Y - Value Z = 0

Tags: excel

I live abroad and I want to send some money back home. The bank will only let me send it in the local currency or 12 other currencies, and mine is not on their list. Therefore I only have the option of sending the local currency, which is Japanese Yen, or Euros. I want to create a spreadsheet, showing me when it would be worth sending in Euros and when it would be worth it sending in Yen. So I have:

```
Option 1: Send Euros
Option 2: Send Yen
```

**Option 1 will require:**
2,000 Yen handling fee
Two currency exchange transactions (Yen ---> Euros ---> Swedish Kroner)

**Option 2 will require:**
2,000 Yen handling fee + 0.1% of amount (minimum 1,500 Yen)
One currency transaction (Yen ---> Swedish Kroner)

So I made the following spreadsheet:

**Exchange Rate**
    JPY/EUR: 143.21
    EUR/SEK: 8.209
    JPY/SEK: 0.058065

**Handling Fee**
    EURO: 2000
    JPY:  3500

**Amount**: 300,000

**Option 1**: 17081.782
**Option 2**: 17216.273

**Amount X: ???**

Here the Amount is set to 300,000 Yen

Option 1 is:

```
        ((300,000 - 2,000) / 143.21) * 8.209
        ((Amount - Handling) / JPY/EUR) * EUR/SEK
```

Option 2 is:

```
        (300,000 - 3,500) * 0.058065
        (Amount - Handling) * JPY/SEK
```

(Handling fee in Option 2 is 2,000 + 0.1% of amount, but minimum 1,500, and since 0.1% of 300,000 is 300, it will always be 1,500 for smaller amounts like 300,000.)

What I want to find out is Amount X, which is the amount where Option 1 - Option 2 = 0.

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I can obtain Amount X through a formula in Excel so that I will always be given the minimal amount I need to send before Option 1 is better than Option 2.

Comment: option 1 - is it 2,000 for each conversion (4,000 total), or 2,000 total?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Basically, the handling fee is from my Japanese bank, so if I send 300,000 it will be:
300,000 - 2,000 / JPY/EUR * EUR/SWE

I already have the other formulas working, but I still need that last one to find the amount X, which will scale with any changes the amount sent or exchange rates.

So basically, what is Amount X when Option 1 - Option 2 = 0
or
What is Amount X when Option 1 - Option 2 = Negative

I typically want to go for Option 2 (send JPY), so I need to find out how much I need to send for it to be a better option that Option 1.

Answer (score 0):

With a layout as below and suitable formulae which you clearly can manage, the results in C9 are `17,081.78 kr` and in E10 `17,216.27 kr`. The balance point is when D2 is `¥119,132`.

[image: SO23540234 example]

This can be achieved with algebra by solving for when:

```
=B9*(D2-D3)/B8
```

equals:

```
=B10*(D2-D3-MAX(1500,E2*0.001))
```

but since the fixed handling fee is common to both options it is slightly easier to calculate the D4 'break-even' value and then add ¥2,000 to it. This would be:

```
 =E5/(1-B9/(B8*B10))
```

Where, as you suggested, E5 might as well be replaced by `1500`. However to spare the algebra involved in solving for D4 Excel has a feature to help. With the first formula above say in G2 and the second in H2 then in I2:

```
=G2-H2
```

is `Option1 - Option2` which is `-134.49` where D2 is ¥300,000. You want this to be `0`, so go to DATA > Data Tools - What-If Analysis, Goal Seek..., and Set cell: `I2`, to value: `0`, By changing cell: `D2`, OK. Excel will then apply a lot of sensible guesswork and in this case should find the answer, which will show in D2 if you click OK again.